# How to manually bind a book without using binding machine?

Tags: book

Is there a tutorial on how to manually use those plastic binding combs without using a binding machine? cause I don't want to buy a binding machine since I won't often use it.

Comment: If you have a local library, they'll probably have one of those machines, so I'd say to ask there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about a book. I think the trick would be punching the holes. You'd have to someone cut 20 or so holes, with just the right spacing and the right size. Once the holes are punched, it's not that hard to put the comb in manually. I've done it plenty of times when I wanted to add or remove pages. You just bend the comb and slide the pages on.

You can get a cheap binding machine for like $40. I don't know what you consider an acceptable amount of money to spend. [http://www.amazon.com/Flexzion-Scrapbook-Laminator-Manually-Capacity/dp/B013SQBRN6/ref=sr_1_13?s=office-products&ie=UTF8&qid=1462641916&sr=1-13&keywords=binding+machine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013SQBRN6) The main difference between the cheap ones and the more expensive ones is how many pages they can punch at a time. I used to have one that could only punch 7 pages, so doing anything sizable took a bunch of time. But if you're not going to use it often, maybe not a big deal.